# show details without using self-joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

i have a table with columns employee_id, employee_name, manager_id. Manager details are also stored in the same employee details table. Now i have to show the result as {Id,EmployeeName,ManagerName} without using self-joins or any other joins.

```
For example :
emp_id   name   manager_id
1        Roy    2
2        Joe    0               
3        raven  2
```

In my resultset i should show Roy and raven with manager name as Joe.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "*without using self-joins or any other joins*" - but why? Is there any reason of such a limitation?

Comment: Yeah Andy. This is one of my sample assignment question and the constraint is you can not use any type of joins.

Comment: Are there any other constraints? Pretty strange assignment since it deprecates to use tools that best fits to the job.

Comment: No.. We can not use any type of joins. That is the only constraint.

Comment: How about a subquery, Can u use that ?
select id, `name`, IFNULL((select `name` from emp where id = m.manager_id),'Boss') ManagerName from emp m;

Comment: you might have to use a cursor, first get requested employees and then iterate over them to fetch the manager details.

Comment: I consider this task a good practice. Beginners tend to join everything and only then muddle their way through their results, where subqueries (be it as derived tables in the FROM clause, a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause or a [NOT] IN or [NOT] EXISTS subquery) would often be more straight-forward and just the better approach.

Comment: @thorstenkettner I think that's completely wrong-headed. While more modern tools are fantastic - both in terms of performance and ease of use - I'm glad I learnt MySQL (just) before they came into existence. I'm sure I'm better at it because of that. Master joins first, then move onto the other stuff.

Comment: @Strawberry: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. What modern tools are you talking about? Subqueries are something very basic in SQL and often neglected unfortunately. I've been using them for some twenty years now where appropriate.

Comment: As I say, I'm referring specifically to MySQL, where they've only been available ca. 2004.

Comment: @Strawberry: Ah, okay, how horrible. Sounds like using a language with nouns only first and only then get introduced to verbs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery.

```
select emp_id,name,
(select name from employee_details a where a.emp_id = b.manager_id) as manager_name  
from employee_details b
```

Comment: Thanks jay. However, I tried this yesterday. but senior told it is a type of join. So you can not use it. Am a bit confused.

Comment: This isn't a join. It's a correlated subquery and fulfills the (daft) brief perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As you are learning, I guess it wouldn't help you much, if I simply showed you the complete query, so instead, I'll tell you how:

It is employee records you want to show plus one additional column, namely the manager name. So select from employee and get the manager name in a subquery in your select clause.

I hope this helps you solve this. If not, come back with further questions.

Comment: Duh, didn't work. You got the complete solution in another answer. I suggest: Close your eyes to it and try it for yourself first :-)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. I tried this yesterday. but senior told it is a type of join. So you can not use it. Am a bit confused.

Comment: They are wrong. This is not considered a join. If they regard any "give me a matching record" a join, then how do they get the matching record without one? This makes no sense.